# Laravel Store only filename when uploading a file

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have the following code to upload and store the file.

```
$user->update([
        'display_profile' => request()->display_profile->storeAs('avatars', $name,'public')
]);
```

This stores the file in the `display_profile` as `avatars/filename.jpg`.

Since I have multiple versions of the files for displaying around the views I am using prefixes like follow

> thumb_filename.jpg
>
> small_filename.jpg
>
> large_filename.jpg

I will need to do a lot of string replace to insert the prefix in place to show the right version of the images. Is there anyway I can save just the filename in the database insteat of the full path?

If not whats the best way to show my files in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this approach mostly:

```sh
$file  = $request->file('display_profile');

$name = $file->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file->extension();

$file->storeAs('public/avatars', $name);

$user->update([
     'display_profile' => $name
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve a file from the request, this will be converted as an [`UploadedFile`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php) object. You can easily retrieve the original name as follow

```php
$file = $request->display_profile;

$user->update([
    'display_profile' => $file->getClientOriginalName()
]);
```

For your second question I suggest you to create a relation with a `Image` class where you can store all the image conversion you require. But this can be a little tricky and may require time to be coded. Fortunately there are tons of libraries that can handle this for you. My favourite is [Laravel medialibrary](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction/)